# Speculative Execution in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I don't see any mention of speculative execution in Apache Beam documentation. But [this post](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/pardo-transformation-apache-beam/read) claims that it has something like that.

> the ParDo transformation is fault-tolerant, i.e. if it crashes, it's
>   rerun. The transformation also has a concept of speculative execution
>   (read about speculative execution in Spark, both are similar basics).
>   The processing for given subset of dataset can be executed on 2
>   different workers at any time. The results coming from the quickest
>   worker are later used and for the slower one are discarded. At this
>   occasion it's important to emphasize that ParDo implementation must be
>   aware of parallel execution on the same subset of data.

Is it true?

Comment: The most relevant doc about execution model is https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/. I don't think it's a standard for all runners. It more likely describes what Dataflow runner does.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `speculative execution` is a responsibility of data processing engine, not Beam. Though, one of the requirement for a Beam transform is to be idempotent because *Beam model provides no guarantees as to the number of times your user code might be invoked or retried* ([see transform requirements](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#requirements-for-writing-user-code-for-beam-transforms)).

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar design in beam. You can look at the documentation here [1] which has lot of details around this topic.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.java#L365